# Deleting elements with largest values from linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a problem with deleting elements with greatest values from doubly linked list. It seems that my program works fine with only one greatest number in the list. However, if the list contains two greatest numbers (as an example, last two list's elements are greatest numbers), the program crashes. I am sure my management of nodes' adresses is not correct.

EDIT: I was ment to say the "greatest" values just in case if the word "largest" mistakens.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    struct node* prev;
    int value;
    struct node* next;
} node;

node* allocateNode(int value);
node* addToEnd(node* head, int value);
node* makeList(node* head, int n);
node* deleteMaxElement(node* head);
void freeMemory(node* head);

int main()
{
    node* head = NULL;
    int n = 0;

    printf("Enter number of elements: ");
    if (!(scanf("%d", &n) == 1))
        return 0;

    head = makeList(head, n);
    head = deleteMaxElement(head);

    if (n > 1)
    {
        node* element = head;
        printf("%d ", element->value);
        while(element->next != NULL)
        {
            element = element->next;
            printf("%d ", element->value);
        }
        printf("\n");
        freeMemory(head);
    }

    return 0;
}

node* makeList(node* head, int n)
{
    int value = 0;
    if (n == 0)
        return head;

    printf("Enter value of 1 node: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &value) == 1)
    {
        head = allocateNode(value);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter value of %d node: ", i + 1);
            if(scanf("%d", &value) == 1)
                head = addToEnd(head, value);
        }
    }
    return head;
}

node* allocateNode(int value)
{
    node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->value = value;
    return newNode;
}

node* addToEnd(node* head, int value)
{
    node* newNode = allocateNode(value);
    node* element = head;

    while (element->next != NULL)
        element = element->next;

    element->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = element;

    return head;
}

node* deleteMaxElement(node* head)
{
    int max = head->value;
    node* element = head;
    // finds max element in list
    while (element->next != NULL)
    {
        element = element->next;
        if (element->value > max)
            max = element->value;
    }
    // max element is in the list head
    int firstElementDeleted = 0;
    if (head->value == max)
    {
        node* temp = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = temp;
        firstElementDeleted = 1;
    }
    // max elements is not in the list head
    element = head;
    while (element->next != NULL)
    {
        node* temp = NULL;
        if (element->value == max)
        {   
            if (!firstElementDeleted)
                (element->prev)->next = element->next;
            else
                head = element->next;
            temp = element->next;
            free(element);
            element = temp;
            continue;
        }
        element = element->next;
    }
    // max elements is in the last node
    if (element->value == max)
    {
        (element->prev)->next = NULL;
        free(element);
    }
    return head;
}

void freeMemory(node* head)
{
    node* next;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        next = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question lacks description of the (shortest) input that results in program crash

Comment: I might have used incorrect word ("largest") for the description. The program should delete elements with greatest/biggest value. For example: `1 2 3 5 5` as the input would result in crash due to access violation. That is where my main question lies as the expected output should be `1 2 3`.  The are no requirements for numbers' lenghts.

Comment: Instead of a single function `delete_max_element` consider splitting the problem into two logic parts (and maybe functions): 1) find max value in a list. 2) Delete all nodes in a list having a specific value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Previous pointer points to nowhere

You do not set the previous node pointer of the next element when you delete the element in the `deleteMaxElement` function. Add this one line to your function and it should work as intended. ;)

```
while (element->next != NULL)
{
    node* temp = NULL;
    if (element->value == max)
    {   
        if (!firstElementDeleted) {
            (element->prev)->next = element->next;
            (element->next)->prev = element->prev;
        }
        else
            head = element->next;
        temp = element->next;
        free(element);
        element = temp;
        continue;
    }
    element = element->next;
}
```